# Cannot Create Outlook 2010 Data File

Tags: windows-8.1, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-registry

I'm running Outlook 2010 on Windows 8.1 and want to backup several imap e-mail files.  Unfortunately, I cannot create a New Outlook Data File. `Home > New Items > More Items > New Outlook Data File` comes up with a dialogue box that has no options to select from. Several forums recommend that the registry key `DisablePST` needs to be set to zero or deleted.  Using regedit, I did a search for `DisablePST`, and there is no such registry key on my computer.  Not sure what else to try, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way to create an Outlook data file (.pst file) is to go via the File menu and the Account settings. The process is described here in detail:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2010/01/24/creating-a-pst-in-outlook-2010.aspx